sveltekit checkbox, checked unchecked then checked again
i have a problem with checkbox. Checking animation isnt smooth as expect. When i click on checkbox its checked then unchecked and checked again. I dont know how can i fix that. i am using sveltekit (svelte 5) and picocss. Can u help me please? Thanks
//+page.svelte
<script>
    import { flip } from 'svelte/animate'
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms'
    import { states } from '$lib/states.svelte'
    let { data, form } = $props()

    const allUsers = $derived(JSON.parse(data.allUsers))
    const currentUser = $derived(JSON.parse(data.user))

    let searchValue = $state('')

    const filteredUsers = $derived(
        allUsers.filter(
            (user) => user.username.includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()) && user._id !== currentUser._id
        )
    )

    $effect(() => {
        console.log(allUsers)
    })
</script>

<div class="container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/app/administration">administration</a></li>
            <li>user access</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <h3>user access</h3>

    <div class="search-bar">
        <input
            class="search"
            type="search"
            name="search"
            bind:value={searchValue}
            placeholder="search"
        />
        {#if searchValue.length > 0}
            {#if searchValue.length > 0}
                <a
                    href="#clear"
                    class="clear-button"
                    onclick={(e) => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        searchValue = ''
                    }}>X</a
                >
            {/if}
        {/if}

        {#if searchValue.length > 0}
            <p>
                searching "{searchValue}"
            </p>
        {/if}
    </div>

    {#if filteredUsers.length > 0}
        <div class="header">
            <p class="title">user</p>
            <p class="admin">admin</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            {#each filteredUsers as user (user._id)}
                <li transition:fade animate:flip={{ duration: 300 }}>
                    <form
                        action="?/admin"
                        method="post"
                        onchange={(e) => {
                            e.currentTarget.requestSubmit()
                        }}
                        use:enhance={() => {
                            states.showLoadingSpinner = true
                            return async ({ update }) => {
                                await update()
                                states.showLoadingSpinner = false
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                        <label for="admin" class="user-row">
                            <p class="user">
                                {user.username}
                            </p>
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                name="admin"
                                id="admin"
                                role="switch"
                                bind:checked={user.admin}
                            />
                        </label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value={user._id} />
                    </form>
                </li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
    {:else}
        <p class="centered-paragraph">No users with this name</p>
    {/if}
</div>

//+page.server.js
import { User } from '$db/models/User'

export const actions = {
    admin: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData()
        const admin = data.get('admin')
        const _id = data.get('id')
        console.log(admin)
        let value
        if (admin === 'on') {
            value = true
        } else {
            value = false
        }

        try {
            const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {
                    _id
                },
                {
                    $set: { admin: value }
                }
            )
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return fail(400, {
                success: false,
                type: 'error',
                message: 'something went wrong'
            })
        }
        return {
            success: true,
            type: 'success',
            message: 'user role has been updated'
        }
    }
}


i want the default value of checkbox be from Db (user.admin) and on click update user in db.
i used e.currentTarget.requestSubmit() to submit a form on change. It works and update db but the checkbox animation makes checked/unchecked/checked
